# Nginx vhost configuration questions

Tags: nginx, virtualhost

I have a NginX vhost, where all static content is served by nginx and anything that's not found or ends with php proxies to apache.

Just wanted to check if I have locations right:

```
location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ @proxy;
  expires 30d;
}

location ~* \.php$ {
   proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.1:8080;
} 

location @proxy {
   proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.1:8080;
}
```

I was also wondering if there is a way to make second location go to third so that I do not have to repeat the proxy_pass line twice?

I have few other questions:

- Does nginx read locations from top to bottom and does it stop looking at next location if curent request matches one of the locations? For example, if server.com/image.jpg is requested, does it mean the very first location declaration will capture it in my locations, and rest will be ignored?
- If I do expires max; or expires 30d; but then site is updated and I want to force user browsers to reload the file right away, is there anything I can do to make them reload?
- my very first location declaration will match anypath that ends with .js, .css, .png and so on, but is it case sensitive? will it also match .PNG ? Should I make it case sensitive or not? If yes, how?
- Is there anything else you think would improve this configuration?

Comment: Many of your questions can be answered just by reading the documentation at: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#location . You cannot make location 2 go to location 3, but you can use an upstream block to prevent repetition of the ip address.

Answer (score 1):

```
location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ @proxy;
  expires 30d;
}

location ~* \.php$ {
   root @proxy;
} 

location @proxy {
   proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.1:8080;
}
```

Should do it

Comment: That's not going to do redirection, forwarding on any have much overhead right?

Comment: I actually just tested it and it does not work.